# Assembly uses System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1 which has a higher version than referenced assembly System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Recently we bought theme from BeyondThemes. When we integrate this with our `MVC4.0` project we are getting below error. Kindly help..

Compilation Error

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

```
CS1705: Assembly \'BeyondThemes.Bootstrap, Version=2.6.3.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\' uses \'System.Web.Mvc, 
Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\'
which has a higher version than referenced assembly \'System.Web.Mvc, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check one of your project is referenced with 4.0 mvc and newly added project has 4.01.

To resolve this:

1. simply Check in your solution all mvc reference.
2. Then check it version using right click on it and property.
3. if possible remove all this reference and add new of 4.0 or 4.01

That's all! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've patched your MVC from 4.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.1 via this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2993928?wa=wsignin1.0

If you have and you still get that error, you'll probably need to reinstall MVC 4 with nuget.

**EDIT:**

Looks like the link is now dead; nuget is probably your best option to update.